# Can Guava's AbstractExecutionThreadService be reused?

Tags: java, service, guava

As far as I can tell, once the run() method of AbstractExecutionThreadService stops, it can't be started again. Is that correct?

I have a service that extends AbstractExecutionThreadService. In my tests I want to start this service, use it, stop it, then start it again. Any suggestions what I can/should do to achieve this while using AbstractExecutionThreadService or AbstractService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Service.start()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.html#start%28%29) states that a stopped `Service` may not be restarted. I'd say just create a new instance of your service and start it each time.

Comment: Yup, Service is really short for ServiceInvocation.